a problem in a radio group using Android studio:java and xml
when creating the radio group I inserted 3 Radio buttons inside it and the first one is checked by default when executing the code  and checking the second one for example the first one is still checked .
<RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radg">

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/agimmob"
                android:textColor="@color/welcomecolor"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
                />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/prop"
                android:textColor="@color/welcomecolor"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
                android:checked="true"

                />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/achet"
                android:textColor="@color/welcomecolor"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"/>

        </RadioGroup>

I tried to make the second one to be checked by default but I got the same problem

Can you share the code you have for handling user taps on the radio buttons?

You have to use the checkedButton property in the RadioGroup component and pass to the property the id of the radioButton that you want to be checked by default
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checkedButton="@id/rb1">

It's not necesarry to use the checked property on the radioRuttons
